# Implementar classe pai

Tags: java, array, herança

Bom, pesquisei bastante, até tenho noção de como funciona, mas não consegui implementar, gostaria de uma luz. Tenho as classes Casa e Edificio, preciso criar uma classe pai Imovel, tendo Casa e Edificio como classes filhas, segue meu código:

```
 package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

public class Porta {
    boolean aberta;
    String cor;
    double dimensaoX, dimensaoY, dimensaoZ;

    void abre() {
        this.aberta = true;
    }
    void fecha() {
        this.aberta = false;
    }
    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
    boolean estaAberta() {
        boolean estaAberta = false;
        if(aberta == true) estaAberta = true;
        return estaAberta;
    }

}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Edificio {
    String cor;
    int totalDePortas;
    int totalDeAndares;
    ArrayList<Porta> portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int qtdPortasAbertas = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<portas.size(); i++) {
            portas.get(i);
            if(portas.get(i).estaAberta() == true) {
                qtdPortasAbertas++;
            }
        }
        return qtdPortasAbertas;
    }

    void adicionaPorta(Porta porta) {
        this.portas.add(porta);
    }

    int totalDePortas() {
        return this.portas.size();
    }

    void adicionaAndar() {
        this.totalDeAndares = totalDeAndares += 1;
    }

    int totalDeAndares() {
        return this.totalDeAndares;
    }
}

package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

public class Casa {
    String cor;
    Porta porta1, porta2, porta3;

    void pinta(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    int quantasPortasEstaoAbertas() {
        int qtdPortasAbertas=0;
        if(porta1.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        if(porta2.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        if(porta3.estaAberta() == true) qtdPortasAbertas++;
        return qtdPortasAbertas;
    }

    int totalDePortas() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

E aqui a classe que preciso tornar a "pai":

```
package br.edu.utfpr.exer05;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Imovel {
    String cor;
    ArrayList<Porta> portas = new ArrayList<Porta>();
}
```

As classes Casa e Edificio estao feitas de formas diferentes pois o exercício pedia, porém tem o mesmo objetivo. Bom, como proceder para criar uma classe pai nos moldes descritos?

Comment: Se for para criar a herança, so faltou o `extends` após o nome das classes assim: `public class Edificio extends Imovel`

Comment: Certo, valeu...Poderia mostrar um exemplo de como ficaria a classe Imovel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve criar a classe `Imovel` com os atributos e métodos que são comuns a todas as classes filhas, para esses atributos e métodos estarem visíveis as classes filhas o modificador de acesso deve ser `protected` ou `public`, feito isso você cria as classes filhas de `Imovel` no seu caso `Casa` e `Edificio` e faça elas herdarem/estenderem de `Imovel`.

Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Imovel{
   // Atributos e Métodos comuns às classes filhas
   protected List<Porta> portas;
   protected String cor;
}

public class Casa extends Imovel{
   // Atributos e Métodos específicos de Casa
}

public class Edificio extends Imovel{
   // Atributos e Métodos específicos de Edificio
}
```

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava, agora entendi. Muito obrigado pelo help.

Comment: estou com o mesmo problema